# PHP: Splitting a string into an array around words wrapped in tildes & keeping those words

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match

It's very late and I think I've been staring at this too long to figure out, but: I have been provided a bunch of raw text where anything within in tildes (`~`) is a title, and everything else is just plain text. However, the text may or may not include newlines; for example:

Title & text on the same line:
`~THE BURGER MINI~A tiny little burger patty in a tiny little bun.`

Title & text on different lines:

```
~THE BURGER MAX~
A gigantic hunk of steak in between two toasted baguettes, each stuffed with beef & cheese`
```

A combination of both:

```
~THE BURGER ZERO~
No burger, no bun, just air.

~THE BURGER ITALIANO~
A soft mix of ground beef & mozzarella stuffed between two pillowy pieces of pasta.~NOTE~This is basically giant ravioli.
```

Ultimately the kind of output I'm trying to achieve would be something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => THE BURGER ZERO
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => No burger, no bun, just air.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => THE BURGER ITALIANO
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [text] => A soft mix of ground beef & mozzarella stuffed between two pillowy pieces of pasta.
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => NOTE
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [text] => This is basically giant ravioli.
        )

)
```

...so I can then differentiate between titles & text, but crucially *in the order they appear*.

I can split the string in newlines into an array with the following:

```
$tempArray = preg_split('/\s*\R\s*/', trim($str), NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

But after that, I get stuck. Using `preg_split` on any group within tildes (`preg_split('/~(.*?)~/uim', $line);`) will give me all of the paragraph text, but loses the titles (as they're being used for the split). I've been banging my head against various forms of `preg_match` & `preg_match_all` but all I'm getting is a headache.

Is there a straightforward way to get what I'm after that would work with all of the above examples?

Comment: May the `text` substring contain newlines?  Why do you want a result with `title` and `text` as separate subarray elements?  Wouldn't it be more useful to keep them in pairs?  I think `preg_split()` is probably the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: I am playing with [this demo](https://3v4l.org/YueSt) Can you offer some of your trickiest possible occurrences?  Do you have edge cases with multibyte characters? Do you have titles that are not all-caps and spaces?  Do you have text that contain tildes?  The quality of the patterns that we can offer you are heavily dependent on the complexity/difficulty of your sample data.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks so much for the demo. At the moment the sample data I have is pretty much just that, but I should be getting a full set tomorrow. You've already raised a couple of things I hadn't considered, but you've definitely put me on the right track.

Comment: I'll look forward to your clarifying [edit]. If the new details permit a better answer than what is already posted, I'll answer; otherwise I'd lean toward Alex's answer for directness.

Comment: Do you want to update your question with new details?

Comment: @mickmackusa Unfortunately I didn't put any more work into this, as the client pivoted away from what they originally wanted to do, so it was basically abandoned.

Comment: So then the decision is yours to define the scope of this question.  One way or another this page should progress to a clear question or the page should be deleted (since you have upvoted answers, I do not recommend that you delete this question).

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/~([^~]+)~\n*([^~\n]+)/', $str, $match);
```

So, match a tilde, followed by one or more of anything but a tilde, followed by another tilde. Capture what's between the tildes:

```
~([^~]+)~
```

Followed by zero or more newlines:

```
\n*
```

Followed by one or more of anything but tildes and newlines. And capture that.

```
([^~\n]+)
```

This will give you the titles in `$match[1]` and the descriptions in `$match[2]`:

```
print_r($match[1]);

Array
(
    [0] => THE BURGER ZERO
    [1] => THE BURGER ITALIANO
    [2] => NOTE
)

print_r($match[1]);

Array
(
    [0] => No burger, no bun, just air.
    [1] => A soft mix of ground beef & mozzarella stuffed between two pillowy pieces of pasta.
    [2] => This is basically giant ravioli.
)
```

Which you might then combine into a single array:

```
$items = array_combine($match[1], $match[2]);
print_r($items);

Array
(
    [THE BURGER ZERO] => No burger, no bun, just air.
    [THE BURGER ITALIANO] => A soft mix of ground beef & mozzarella stuffed between two pillowy pieces of pasta.
    [NOTE] => This is basically giant ravioli.
)
```

Comment: This is smart, and I think probably the `array_combine()` is what I was missing/trying to figure out, but ran out of brains. I haven't been given all the copy that I'd need to parse yet, but I know there are already a couple of curveballs I hadn't considered 

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$input = '~THE BURGER ZERO~
No burger, no bun, just air.

~THE BURGER ITALIANO~
A soft mix of ground beef & mozzarella stuffed between two pillowy pieces of pasta.~NOTE~This is basically giant ravioli.';

$splittedText = array_values(array_filter(explode ("~", $input)));

foreach($splittedText as $key => $value){
    if (ctype_upper(str_replace(' ', '', $value))){
        $splittedText[$key] = ['title' => $value];
    }
    else{
        $splittedText[$key] = ['text' => $value];
    }
}

print_r($splittedText);
```

This solution is without the usage of any regex.

How it works is that

- First explode the whole string on the wave dash
- Then clean the array from empty spots, rearrange keys and iterate the array
- Check if the value that we are iterating is all capitals (removing the spaces), if it is then we set the key to be "title" otherwise it's "text" as stated in the expected output.

The output is:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => THE BURGER ZERO
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => 
No burger, no bun, just air.


        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => THE BURGER ITALIANO
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [text] => 
A soft mix of ground beef & mozzarella stuffed between two pillowy pieces of pasta.
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => NOTE
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [text] => This is basically giant ravioli.
        )

)
```

Comment: This may not be reliable because the `text` may legitimately contain the title-wrapping character (tilde).

Comment: Based on the input example the tilde is used only to contain titles, so can not be a part of the text or title string. Judging based on the input string-example at least. But you are right on your comment, if the tilde is used other that differentiate text from titles can lead to errors in matching.

Comment: @mickmackusa It's a fair point, and actually you raised a couple of good questions in your other comments with regards to newlines; but all of the content should be standard text, and there definitely shouldn't be any tildes in it, as I've been told they are the 'title delimiters'

Answer (score 1):

A way with `preg_split` that has the useful option `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` that returns captured parts of the delimiter:

```
$str = <<<TEXT
~THE BURGER ZERO~
No burger, no bun, just air.

~TRICKY TEST~
Meet me ~5pm.

~THE BURGER ITALIANO~
A soft mix of ground beef & mozzarella stuffed between two pillowy pieces of pasta.~NOTE~This is basically giant ravioli.

~THE BURGER MINI~A tiny little burger patty in a tiny little bun.
TEXT;

$pattern = '/ \s* ~ ( [\p{Lu} ]+ ) ~ \s* /ux';

$arr = preg_split($pattern, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r(array_chunk($arr, 2));
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/5JtqS#v8.2.4)